# JavaScript attach listener to table column in order to sort

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, onclicklistener, event-listener

I have a sorting alogithm for table columns, and I want to attach a listener to certain column in order to sort it after click.

Later, I'm updating the table, so I (probably) need to remove previous listener, and add a new one. In order to remove previous listener, I need to have a reference to the function.

Now my code looks like this

```
function sortTable(elem) {
        console.log('clicked');
        const table = elem.closest('table');
        const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
        Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
            .sort(comparer(Array.from(elem.parentNode.children).indexOf(elem), this.asc = !this.asc))
            .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr));
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', sortTable));
```

But I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: elem.closest is not a function
    at HTMLTableCellElement.sortTable
```

It works when I use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', function() {
   sortTable(th);
}));
```

But as I said, I need to remove (or update) the event listener for table columns later, because my table is dynamically changing. So I would need to call something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.removeEventListener('click', sortTable));

// or add listener again with the same function reference, and it will be updated? tell me if I'm wrong
```

But I can't make it all work :(

Can you help me please?

EDIT:
Thanks for the comment. It works now. I changed `sortTable(elem)` to `sortTable(event)`, and replaced `elem` inside function with `this`.
Then I can call the function with:

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', sortTable));
```

Comment: `sortTable` gets called with an `event` object, not an element. I suspect you meant to use `this` instead of the parameter `elem` (which should be renamed to `event`)

Comment: oh, my mistake.. thanks for your help, it works now ;)